# If you were to explicitly call the `__enter__()` and `__exit_()` methods instead of using a `with` statement, what would the code look like?

Tags: python, python-3.x, with-statement

If you were to explicitly call the `__enter__()` and `__exit_()` methods instead of using a `with` statement, what would the code look like?

Code using a `with` statement:

```python
with open("test.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write("Hello, World!")
```

Failed attempt to re-write the code

The goal is to replace the `with`-statement with explicit calls to `__enter__()` and `__exit__()`

```python
file = open("test.txt", "w")
try:
    file.__enter__()
    file.write("Hello, World!")
    file.__exit__()
except BaseException as exc:
    exc_class, exc_object, traceback = something_some_some()
    file.__exit__(exc_class, exc_object, traceback)
finally:
    pass
```

Comment: If you're reproducing a `with` statement, you need to call `__exit__` in the `finally` block of your `except` statement (and nowhere else).

Comment: The [documentation for `with` statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement)  provides you with the equivalent code

Answer (score 2):

Following the desugaring at https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement:

```
manager = open("test.txt", "w")
enter = type(manager).__enter__
exit = type(manager).__exit__
value = enter(manager)
hit_except = False

try:
    file = value
    file.write("Hello, World!")
except:
    hit_except = True
    if not exit(manager, *sys.exc_info()):
        raise
finally:
    if not hit_except:
        exit(manager, None, None, None)
```

Note that the bare `except` is intentional here; *any* exception should trigger the `__exit__` method. Saving bound methods for `__enter__` and `__exit__` is done, I think, to prevent `__enter__` from being executed before verifying that the supposed context manager actually has an `__exit__` method.